Why my serial monitor is showing unreadable character using Espressif IDE?
I wanted to work on a project using the ESP32-C2 Module ESP8684. I flashed the Hello World code example, but the serial monitor is showing unreadable characters.
I first tried using the Espressif VSCode extension, but the monitor didn’t work. Then I tried the Espressif IDE running on Eclipse, but the problem persisted—the monitor still displayed unreadable characters.
In both cases, I tried changing the baud rate, but nothing improved. Additionally, in the Espressif IDE, when I open the serial monitor, the Windows system notification sound plays randomly (this sound: windows sound).
In both instances, I simply opened the Hello World project, selected the correct device and COM port, built it, and flashed it without making any changes. I’ve also tried reinstalling everything multiple times, following Espressif’s installation instructions, but the issue persists.
Serial Monitor
Hello World code:
/*
 * SPDX-FileCopyrightText: 2010-2022 Espressif Systems (Shanghai) CO LTD
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include "sdkconfig.h"
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "esp_chip_info.h"
#include "esp_flash.h"
#include "esp_system.h"

void app_main(void)
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");

    /* Print chip information */
    esp_chip_info_t chip_info;
    uint32_t flash_size;
    esp_chip_info(&chip_info);
    printf("This is %s chip with %d CPU core(s), %s%s%s%s, ",
           CONFIG_IDF_TARGET,
           chip_info.cores,
           (chip_info.features & CHIP_FEATURE_WIFI_BGN) ? "WiFi/" : "",
           (chip_info.features & CHIP_FEATURE_BT) ? "BT" : "",
           (chip_info.features & CHIP_FEATURE_BLE) ? "BLE" : "",
           (chip_info.features & CHIP_FEATURE_IEEE802154) ? ", 802.15.4 (Zigbee/Thread)" : "");

    unsigned major_rev = chip_info.revision / 100;
    unsigned minor_rev = chip_info.revision % 100;
    printf("silicon revision v%d.%d, ", major_rev, minor_rev);
    if(esp_flash_get_size(NULL, &flash_size) != ESP_OK) {
        printf("Get flash size failed");
        return;
    }

    printf("%" PRIu32 "MB %s flash\n", flash_size / (uint32_t)(1024 * 1024),
           (chip_info.features & CHIP_FEATURE_EMB_FLASH) ? "embedded" : "external");

    printf("Minimum free heap size: %" PRIu32 " bytes\n", esp_get_minimum_free_heap_size());

    for (int i = 10; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("Restarting in %d seconds...\n", i);
        vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
    printf("Restarting now.\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    esp_restart();
}


What baud rate did you set in your IDE?  How did you determine that was correct?

@TimRoberts I changed the baudrate viea the sdkconfig file and via the menuconfig, especially the two parameters : CONFIG_ESP_CONSOLE_UART_BAUDRATE and CONFIG_CONSOLE_UART_BAUDRATE. I didn't determine which speed was correct, I just tested a different speeds and combinations but it never worked. Actually the baudrate is 115200.

There are two UARTs on that chip.  Are you sure you're connecting to the right one?   Do you have the clock configured correctly?  The baud rate derives from the system clock.
